# Unique document ids with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a question about Kafka, and Unique Document Ids.

When using data stores such as MongoDB or SQL databases, it is relatively easy to generate a concept for a Unique Document Id.

MongoDB literally has an `_id` field which is a unique id generated using an algorithm, which if I recall correctly is based around UUID + a timestamp.

SQL tables (can) have auto increment primary keys.

Data sent to Kafka is stored on a Topic using a key which dictates the Partition, and each piece of data is stamped with an offset.

From this, it looks like the combination

```
(Topic, Partition, Offset)
```

might be suitable as a concept for a Unique Identifier for each message.

However, this approach has some drawbacks. If data is copied from one topic to another, the combination of these three identifiers will change. Having said that, the same is true for autoincrement primary keys in SQL or ObjectIds in Mongo.

Is using `(Topic, Partition, Offset)` as a Unique Identifier a bad idea? I have previously considered the value of a messages' `Topic` and `Offset` to be implementation detail rather than something which client code should be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the simplest solution would be to simply generate a UUID and write it to value or header when sending a message by the producer.